# Bluetooth not working on HP 15-BS1XX Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, bluetooth, realtek

```
lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net; lsusb; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'; rfkill list
```

gives the following results

```
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [103c:832b]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:d723]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:8319]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8723de
    Kernel modules: rtl8723de
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1bcf:2c9b Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:b009 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
[    0.031326] Spectre V2 : Enabling Restricted Speculation for firmware calls
[    0.115367] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[   35.807624] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   35.807635] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   35.807637] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   35.807639] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   35.807642] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   36.684313] [drm] Finished loading DMC firmware i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_01.bin (v1.1)
[   38.140139] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1001 tx timeout
[   41.355373] rtl8723de: Using firmware rtlwifi/rtl8723defw.bin
[   46.300160] Bluetooth: hci0: HCI_OP_READ_LOCAL_VERSION failed (-110)
[   49.526409] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   49.526410] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   49.526412] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

I'm using ubuntu 18.04 with 4.15.0-88-generic kernal

Please help

Comment: For testing purposes, could you please install `apt install linux-generic-hwe-18.04` to check, if a more recent kernel has a working module?

Comment: Just to be sure, if I do install this, is there a way to revert back to the previous kernel?